# Getting the correct price per activity using MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

We are developing a card check-in system in C# with MySql. Depending on the time the user checks-in, a different amount is charged to the user. We have a price table that specifies the price during the entire day per hour. When the user checks-in, I need to be able to know how much that check-in cost. Below are the tables I have:

### ACTIVITY TABLE:

```
CARD_ID      CLOCK

1            5/26/2013 10:40:47 AM
2            5/26/2013 10:48:50 AM
3            5/26/2013 12:00:00 AM
4            5/26/2013 14:40:20 AM
```

### PRICE TABLE

```
TIME         PRICE
00:00        4
01:00        4
02:00        4
03:00        4
04:00        4
05:00        4
06:00        4
07:00        4
08:00        6
09:00        6
10:00        6
11:00        6
12:00        6
13:00        7
14:00        7
15:00        7
16:00        7
17:00        7
18:00        8
19:00        8
20:00        4
21:00        4
22:00        4
23:00        4
```

I am trying to figure out the best approach here to get this. Is there a way I can get this with a query? Once I know the price, I can be able to insert this into a transaction table. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this solve the problem perfectly well. Anyone - if performance becomes an issue, please look at Aron's answer below which is also good. Thanks to both for a great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.card_id, a.clock, p.price
FROM activity a
INNER JOIN price p
ON HOUR(a.clock) = HOUR(p.time)
```

Comment: +1 damn...that is prob the simplest way to do this...although on the downside this would not take advantage of any of your indices...so will not scale well..

Comment: Sarwar026, it works perfect and simple. Thank you so much for your valuable contribution.

Comment: Aron, any suggestions for the indices? I did not think about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    price,
    CARD_ID,
    clock
from activity a
join price p on  p.time <= TIME(a.clock)
  AND 
TIME(a.clock) < ADDTIME(p.time, '01:00:00')
```

This might not work correctly when your time is close to the hour mark since I have no idea how MySQL time compare works then and to be honest I find MySQL pretty sketchy in general.

Comment: Hi Aron, thanks for your help. This won't work as it is, the clock is a timestamp datatype column and the time column in the price table is of "time" datatype. Should I convert the click date into hours/minutes?

Comment: my bad...hope that fixed it..added the `TIME(expr)` function to extract the time part...not sure if it works with `TIMESTAMP` type

Comment: thanks Aron again for your help. Unfortunately this wont get any results, most probably because it doesn't match with the time (maybe datatype thing)

Comment: ack...forgot the add...checked on SQLFiddle (which I don't normally use so thanks to peterm for that).

Comment: Aron, I also gave your last answer like valid because it works well. In terms of performance, which query is better, yours or sarwar026?

Comment: mine by a tiny bit I would imagine...I have no data to go on mind. I would suggest you go with sarwar's for now. Put a comment to this discussion next to the code and note that if performance gets a bit crap to take another look...sarwar's is MUCH clearer.

Comment: Thanks Aron for your honesty, will do that thanks a lot and thanks again for your help.